# Unintended multiple PHP versions on OSX

Tags: macos, php

For an application i'm making i need the PHP [stats](https://pecl.php.net/package/stats) functions. My OSX (10.11) came with the default PHP 5.5, but i needed 7.0 to install the PECL stats package so i updated my local PHP version to version 7 with the shellscript on liip.ch, like so:

`curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0`

Now i ended up with, apparently, two php versions.

When i run `phpinfo()` on a page i get **PHP Version 7.0.2** and when (in the terminal) i do `php -v` i end up with **PHP 5.5.27**.

It seems that for my web applications the update works (i got a stricter notice for example), but when i try to install the stats package with `pecl install stats` i get **pecl/stats requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.5.27**

`which php` gives me just one result: `/usr/bin/php`

How can i tell my terminal to 'use' php 7 as well?

Comment: What is the command to uninstall PHP? Run that, try `php -v`, uninstall again if the wrong PHP version still exists, install PHP 7, and finally profit? Basically, it sounds like the environmental variable named PHP was simply not updated when you installed PHP 7 so pecl stats is merely using the environmental variable to figure out your PHP version. Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/q/7501678/2191572

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to uninstall, and it's normal what happened. When you install Apache gets to use the version you installed but the env path for console remains with the default osx php version.

You should read **Frequently Asked Questions** on the page http://php-osx.liip.ch/. Look for the first item.